# Connect local network machine as a FTP machine

Tags: networking, ftp, local

I have network of 20-30 machine.
I want to connect to other machines from my machine as FTP.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Why do you want to connect via FTP?

Generally, you can connect with an FTP-client to every machine that has an FTP Server running and correctly configured.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy and configure a FTP server and enter those local machines' resources' paths to that FTP server. Then you simply connect to that FTP server and browse paths which will be the resources of those local machines actually...